# SOAP UI doesnt generate wsdl-interface

Tags: java, spring, soapui, spring-ws

I am trying to test my soap web service by SOAP-UI, Also I use Spring-ws and Java.

I point to my wsdl file in spring configuration like this:

```
  <bean id="myservice" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.SimpleWsdl11Definition">
   <constructor-arg value="/WEB-INF/wsdl/myservice.wsdl"/>
</bean>
```

Then in the SOAP UI I locate this wsdl file, but it does not create and WSDL-interface that I can work with to create requests.

But If I use the exactly same xsd but dynamically create the wsdl file than SOAP UI creates the wsdl interface fine:

```
    <sws:dynamic-wsdl id="myservice"
      portTypeName="MyService"
      locationUri="/myService"
      targetNamespace="http://mypath">
      <sws:xsd location="/mypath.xsd"/>
  </sws:dynamic-wsdl>
```

What am I missing? I need modify my wsdl file and not work directly with spring auto generated wsdl.

Comment: Feels like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620762/spring-ws-how-to-create-wsdl-from-an-xsd-with-no-request-element ... But in disguise ...

Comment: @M. Deinum No, different, this is about SOAP UI directly, I didnt want to ask 2 questions in one question so divided into two