# Spring WS: How to get and save XSD validation errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-ws

I use SpringWS for my soap service and validate it like this;

```
 <sws:interceptors>
    <bean id="payloadValidatingInterceptor" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor">
        <property name="schema" value="/schemas/my.xsd"/>
        <property name="validateRequest" value="false"/>
        <property name="validateResponse" value="true"/>
    </bean>
```

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE,  localPart = "ServiceProvider")
@ResponsePayload
public ServiceProviderTxn getAccountDetails(@RequestPayload ServiceProviderrequest)
{ ...}
```

This works fine but when there is an error it returns a spring generated error response before it reaches to the endpoint, so I never have a chance to process them. But I want to be able to **log and save the full error message to database**. One way I found out is to do something like this in my other question;

[Spring WS How to get all error messages when validation fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30671052/spring-ws-how-to-get-all-error-messages-when-validation-fails)

But it does not work as I want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can extend `PayloadValidationInterceptor` and redefine the method

```
protected boolean handleRequestValidationErrors(MessageContext messageContext, SAXParseException[] errors)
```

If you look at the standard implementation (available [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws/blob/master/spring-ws-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/ws/soap/server/endpoint/interceptor/AbstractFaultCreatingValidatingInterceptor.java)) you can see how it dumps all the parsing errors; you can also dump the incoming message since you have access to messageContext and its getRequest() method. Your class xould be something like

```
public class PayloadValidationgInterceptorCustom extends
PayloadValidatingInterceptor {

@Override
protected boolean handleRequestValidationErrors(MessageContext messageContext, SAXParseException[] errors)
        throws TransformerException {
    messageContext.getRequest().writeTo(/*place your Outputstream here something like a ByteArrayOutputStream*/); //use this if you want to dump the message
    for (SAXParseException error : errors) {
        //dump the each error on the db o collect the stack traces in a single string and dump only one or to the database
       /*you can use something like this
         StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
         PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
         error.printStackTrace(pw);
         sw.toString();
         to get the stack trace
        */

    }
    return super.handleRequestValidationErrors(messageContext,errors);

}
```

Comment: tnx but could you extend your answer with code and combine with the answer that I described on my link? It more sounds like a theory rather than a working solution

Comment: @Spring: added a sample class

Comment: I tried but handleRequestValidationErrors is never called

Comment: I did a test case and my interceptor is called, my guess is that you are using the conf posted in the question where <property name="validateRequest" value="false"/> you must set it to true

Comment: tnx could you also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30850182/spring-response-time