# Spring: Response time

Tags: java, spring, spring-ws

I have a SOAP webservice(spring ws)and need to save the response time of every request that I receive. I could create a servlet filter that measures time difference between HTTP Request and HTTP Response. But, I need to log the response time together with some values that I read from soap request envelope, and since at that time request is raw and needs to be unmarshalled, that's an expensive and redundant operation to unmarshall for every request.

So is there a way to calculate it using SpringWS? like in a payloadInterceptor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, implementing an [`EndpointInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/server/EndpointInterceptor.html) is the best fit for this task, as it gives you access to the SOAP messages through the `MessageContext`. See the [Reference Documenation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/reference/html/server.html#server-endpoint-interceptor).

Comment: there are many implementing classes of that interface, which one suits best? I already have a PayloadValidatorInterceptor, but how do I pass value(the requestTime) between the overridden request and response methods in that class? thats a singleton

Comment: you can use the MessageContext set/getProperty api to keep some state between request and response. EndpointInterceptorAdapter may be you best fit to implement the interceptor

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use two tools.

1. AspectJ with its annotation @Before and @AfterReturning. The pointcut could be the method that receives the request (@WebMethod).

   ```
   @Before("call([package, class and method that receives the request]")
   public void before(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
       ...
   }

   @AfterReturning(pointcut = "call([package, class and method that receives the request])", returning = "result")
   public void after(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) throws Throwable {
       ...
   }
   ```

The JoinPoint object has the information of the method's parameters

2. Override the method handleMessage of a custom class that implements the SOAPHandler class. This method will be executed every time a SOAP request is received.

I hope this can give you ideas to resolve your problem.

Comment: I am implementing the web service not the client which uses it

Comment: The same approach could be used in the web service. I edited my answer.

Comment: `SOAPHandler` is a JAX-WS/JEE class, and is not used/supported by Spring-WS.